# org/bson/conversions/Bson error in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, bson

I have installed Zeppelin 0.9.0 on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

In interpreters spark.jars I have mongo-spark-connector, mongo-java-driver and bson.

I successfully imported com.mongodb.spark, org.bson.Document and other necessary packages, but when I want to execute

```
val rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc)
```

appears error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/conversions/Bson
> ... 66 elided
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bson.conversions.Bson
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ... 66 more

Also, I have spark version 3.1.1, java version 11.0.10, scala version 2.12.10.

Comment: what are versions of mongo dependencies?

Comment: mongo-java-driver-3.6.3,
bson-4.3.1,,
mongo-spark-connector_2.12-3.0.1.
I also tried with the newest versions, and error appears again.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.
I've put the following jars in interpreter/spark/dep folder and it works:

- bson-4.3.1.jar
- mongodb-driver-core-4.3.1.jar
- mongo-java-driver-3.12.10.jar
- mongo-spark-connector_2.12-3.0.1.jar
- zeppelin-mongodb-0.9.0.jar